# Connecting a form to email via Contact Form 7 on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

I have the following form code:

```
<center> 

<label for=".elementor-6 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5m0lukt .wpcf7 input[type="text"]"><input type=text text* your-name placeholder="name" required id:name </input></label>

<label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-tel* your-email"> <input type="phone" tel* tel-196 input placeholder="phone" id:phone required</input></label>


<textarea name="details" placeholder="your message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea details" id="details" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>

[submit "send"]
</center>
```

but I'm unable to set the mail tags properly in order to connect it to the email so I only receive blank messages. I get notified when the form is filled out, but I don't see any details from the fields. I know it has something to do with mail tags, but I'm not sure how to change the following accordingly:

```
From: your-name <[your-email]>
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]
```

Is there any way to get it to work without changing the HTML code much, since I have CSS code designing my form?
Any help here is appreciated because I'm completely lost, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below the Message Body, change [your-message] with [details]

Comment: What about the rest of the fields? Name and email?

Answer (score 1):

Okay the person above made me try a couple of things and I just added a "textarea name=" to the rest of the fields. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it somehow got me see the messages I'm receiving.